# Savepoint state keeps growing

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to do a savepoint and reconfigure my window aggregation jobs overtime and I noticed that the windowed results keep accumulating with time (I'm using heap backend). I modified the snapshot code and noticed that Flink does not drop my aggregated window states after the window has closed -- I'm seeing accumulated window data that looks like

```
(0|TimeWindow{start=1679953570000, end=1679953580000})=(1679953570838,...
(0|TimeWindow{start=1679953650000, end=1679953660000})=(1679953654647,...
(0|TimeWindow{start=1679953540000, end=1679953550000})=(1679953542344,...
.....
```

after printed out [snapshot logic for heap memory backend](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/dbab73e5d097518838283a7a4f056cca0ac3f9a5/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/state/heap/CopyOnWriteStateTableSnapshot.java#L93). It seems all non-outstanding windows are still preserved as part of the state. This prevents me to do savepoints overtime due to the state size and I'm wondering is there a way for me to force Flink to remove the windowed results after triggered. I'm testing an older version (1.4.1) and I can't migrate to newer version due to the changes to the source code. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You'd want to include details on how you're assigning watermarks. But Flink 1.4 is so old that it's hard to remember whether there were issues with windowing state back then...

Comment: I agree with @kkrugler - You should really update your Flink version